# ValueError: could not convert string to float - Mutual Information

Tags: python, feature-selection, mutual-information

I have a data base with categorical values, and i'm trying to use the feature selection based on mutual information. And just in the beggining i'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Mr. Michael Hall'
```

`

This was what I am trying to do:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
mutual_info = mutual_info_classif(X_train_cat, y_train)
```

Does anyone know why this is gaving me this error?

Comment: Post whole code

Answer (score 0):

> could not convert string to float

You are getting this error because it expects a float data type.
Float data type contains value like `1.00,2.21,3.14,1234.42132,12413.1241413...` and so on.

Data which you are passing is of type string.

To get mutual information you need to pass float data type instead of string.

[To know more about mutual information](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html)

In order for us to help you more please give us sample dataset.